# Display menu icon and text with actionViewClass="SearchView"

Tags: android, android-menu

All - I'm using the AppCompat library for my application, and I'm trying to display a menu item with `actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

I'd like the title *and* icon to display on the bar, so I'm using the following code:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Locations"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

but the title isn't displaying. Any ideas how to get the title to display?